# Pandas DataFrame and numpy standard deviation are different

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

simply asking, why this std are different?

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> arr = [10, 386, 479, 627, 20, 523, 482, 483, 542, 699, 535, 617, 577, 471, 615, 583, 441, 562, 5
63, 527, 453, 530, 433, 541, 585, 704, 443, 569, 430, 637, 331, 511, 552, 496, 484, 566, 554, 472, 3
35, 440, 579, 341, 545, 615, 548, 604, 439, 556, 442, 461, 624, 611, 444, 578, 405, 487, 490, 496, 3
98, 512, 422, 455, 449, 432, 607, 679, 434, 597, 639, 565, 415, 486, 668, 414, 665, 763, 557, 304, 4
04, 454, 689, 610, 483, 441, 657, 590, 492, 476, 437, 483, 529, 363, 711, 543]
>>> elements = numpy.asarray(arr)
>>> arr_D = {"A":arr}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr_D)
>>>
>>> print(numpy.std(elements, axis=0))
118.51857760182034
>>> print(numpy.std(df['A']))
118.5185776018204
>>> print(df['A'].std(axis=0))
119.15407050904474
```

Is it problem with my comprehension of topic? As far as i know there pandas use numpy. datafram std and numpy std of same column should be same.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*pandas* uses the [Unbiased estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) by default and *numpy* does not by default, So neither of them are incorrect they use different approach to calculate **std**
To make *numpy* use *Unbiased estimation* pass `ddof=1` to `std`

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas

>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(100))

>>> numpy.std(df[0]) #default std biased estimation
0.2877601644414916

>>> numpy.std(df[0],ddof=1) #with ddof=1 i.e unbiased estimation
0.2892098469889083

>>> df[0].std() # unbiased estimation match with numpy std with ddof=1
0.2892098469889083
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy uses biased std and pandas unbiased. In other words, numpy divides by `n` (number of elements) and pandas divides by `n-1`. Try following to see that if matches:

```
print(df['A'].std(axis=0)/np.sqrt(len(arr))*np.sqrt((len(arr)-1)))
#118.51857760182033
```